# MariaDB boolen transition SQL

Tags: mariadb, boolean, state, transition

Using MariaDB version 8.0.19, what is the best method for detecting a boolean transition?

E.g. raw data could be:

```
1
1
1
0
0
1
1
1
0
0
```

I want to count either rising edge transition or falling, so on rising, from 0 to 1, the return would be 2 for the above data. The column datatype is tinyint. Pseudo-code, I'm thinking something like:

```
select SUM(status)
where status = '1'
and the row previous to it = '0'
```

There is a CURRENT_TIMESTAMP column, and an index, if that helps. Granularity is 1 second intervals.

Tried:

```sql
SELECT site, ffr as "2m", COUNT(ffr) as "2m qty", por as "5m", COUNT(por) as "5m qty", dt as "dateTime" FROM phgt
WHERE dt >= '2023-12-18 08:00:00'
  AND dt <  '2023-12-21 20:00:00'
GROUP by ffr, por, hour(dt), day(dt)
ORDER by idphgt desc
```

to get started, looking for ideas on how to capture the transition

Comment: Note the data is in one column, when I pasted it I pasted it as so, guess I should have used a code block, sorry I'm new here :)

Comment: Why would it be 2?

Comment: You should be able to do this using the `LAG()` window function.

Comment: @P.Salmon I guess they're counting the first row as a rise.

Comment: @Barmer first? I see no way of establishing sequence of events

Comment: It would be two, because there are quantity two transitions from 0 to 1 in that sequence of data. I will have a look at LAG(), thanks.

Comment: Also `8.0.19` is a rather odd MariaDB version. Looks more MySQLish. [Window Functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/window-functions/).

Comment: `LAG` was first available in MySQL 8.0 and MariaDB 10.2.  Use `ORDER BY` to sort the rows so `LAG(1)` refers to the "previous row".

Answer (score 0):

`LAG` was first available in MySQL 8.0 and MariaDB 10.2.  Use `ORDER BY` to sort the rows so `LAG(1)` refers to the "previous row".  "Boolean" values are essentially the numbers "0" and "1".